# How to extract attributes and text from HTML?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have datafiles containing data like

```
<li class="speaker_index js_only" id="si_4178514"
    data-si_id="4178514" data-speaker_id="20864"
    data-start_offset="9"
    data-end_offset="125">
    <h5>
        <span class="icon-user">speaker: </span>James Brown
        <span class="item_time"><span class="icon-time" title="time">, time: </span>00:01:56</span>
    </h5>
    <p>The chairman opens the meeting</p>
</li>
```

I would to process this kind of data retrieving the result below

```
start=9
end=125
speaker=James Brown
text=The chairman opens the meeting
```

I could look for various symbols and extract the data I need, but I suppose this can be done much structured and in a general manner (maybe by using regex ?).
Best would be to create an array of a objects (each having keys `start`, `end`, `speaker`, `text`).

What is the best and easiest way achieving my goal using JavaScript?

Comment: Don't use regex. Do use DOM.

Comment: if it is always well-formatted html, you could try converting it to xml and doing an xpath search on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is valid XML, which it seems to be, then you can do a simple XSLT transform such as:

```
<xsl:template match="li">
    start=<xsl:value-of select="@data-start_offset"/>
    end=<xsl:value-of select="@data-end_offset"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    text=<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

If you don't want to get involved with XSLT, then following @Rhumborl's suggestion, you could load the HTML into the browser, which is after all one of the best HTML parsers out there, and then access what you want via the following (no need for jQuery here unless you're a masochist or really want to support archaic browsers):

```
start = document.querySelect('li').getAttribute('data-start_offset');
```

or if you prefer

```
start = document.querySelect('li').dataset.start_offset
```

and so on. Or, you could use xpath as he mentioned:

```
start = document.evaluate('//li/@data-start_offset', ...);
```

You could write a quick JS program and run it under a headless browser such as PhantomJS, and output the desired results directly to the console, as in

```
console.log("start=", start);
```

and run it as

```
phantomjs extract_data.js input.js > output
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining various possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using JavaScript, you can use jQuery for this.

Example for getting the start value (note that instead of the selector, you can also pass a string containing HTML):

```
var $data = $("#data");
var $li = $("li", $data);
var startOffset = $li.attr("data-start_offset");

alert("start: " + startOffset);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j8drarha/5/

Comment: (1) He didn't say he is using JavaScript. (2) To say that as you are using JavaScript, you can use jQuery, is a non-sequitur.

Comment: "What is the best and easiest way achieving my goal using JavaScript?" is the last line of OP's questions and the javascript tag is present as well.

Comment: Oops, sorry. However, the "non-sequitur" portion of my comment stands.